# How to refer to another table in a CASE WHEN Statement in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I'd like to set column3 in  table1 to a specific value by checking if a certain threshold (Queried by intersection) is exceeded. My first table holds geometry information with additional columns,the same is true for my second table. I finally ended up with this code:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET column3 = CASE

                    WHEN t.x >15 THEN 1
                    ELSE 0

                  END

    FROM LATERAL (SELECT table2.column7 AS x FROM table2 WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(table1.geom, table2.geom)) AS t;
```

But I get a message: `ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "table1"`,

with a hint: `HINT:  There is an entry for table "table1", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.`

What is wrong about my syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are updating the entire table, you don't need a lateral join. Of course there must be a 1:1 relation between the two tables.

```
UPDATE table1
    SET column3 = (
      SELECT 
        CASE
         WHEN table2.column7 >15 THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END
      FROM table2 
      WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(table1.geom, table2.geom)
     --LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: no need for a sub-select even I guess; only for a `LIMIT` statement